# add button to each row using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using javascript and Jquery, I am trying to add a button for each row. I want to add a click event to button of each row. 
Here is my code:

```
reportModal = UIkit.modal("#report_modal");
$('#report_modal').empty();

var gridHtml = "<table id='table1'>"
                  +"    <thead>"
                  +"      <tr>"
                  +"          <th>FirstName</th>"
                  +"          <th>Age</th>"
                  +"          <th>Tel</th>"                 
                  +"          <th>Button</th>"  
                  +"      </tr>"
                  +"      </thead>"
                  +"     <tbody></tbody>"
                  +"</table>";

$('#report_modal').html(gridHtml);                

var data = {};
       data.d = [{FirstName: 'AAA', Age: '20', Tel: '111'}, 
                {FirstName: 'BBB', Age: '98', Tel: '222'},
                {FirstName: 'CCC', Age: '45', Tel: '333'}];     
var trHTML = '';

for(var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++){

  trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data.d[i].FirstName + '</td><td>' + data.d[i].Age + '</td><td>' + '<a onclick="showMsg(${data.d[i].FirstName})" href="#"><i class="flaticon-icon-path"></i></a>' + '</td></tr>';
}               

$('#report_modal').append(trHTML);

function showMsg(msg){
  alert(msg);
}
```

My problem is that when click in buttons the showMsg function is called but it show "undefined";

Please any idea to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: you've gotta use "Template literals" `` in order to use string interpolation 
or classic sctring concatenation `<a onclick="showMsg(' + data.d[i].FirstName + '"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is syntax error:
use `onclick="showMsg(\''+data.d[i].FirstName+'\')"`

Like this:

```
   trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data.d[i].FirstName + '</td><td>' + data.d[i].Age + '</td><td>' + '<a onclick="showMsg(\''+data.d[i].FirstName+'\')" href="#"><i class="flaticon-icon-path"></i></a>' + '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use ["Template literals"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) `` in order to use string interpolation. Moreover in thiat case you can use multiline string!

```
trHTML += `<tr>
  <td>${data.d[i].FirstName}</td>
  <td>${data.d[i].Age}</td>
  <td>
    <a onclick="showMsg(${data.d[i].FirstName})" href="#">
      <i class="flaticon-icon-path"></i>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>`;
```

or use classic string concatenation

```
trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data.d[i].FirstName + '</td><td>' + data.d[i].Age + '</td><td>' + '<a onclick="showMsg(' + data.d[i].FirstName + '" href="#"><i class="flaticon-icon-path"></i></a>' + '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: FYI jQuery supports this more readable syntax : `row = $("<tr/">)` , or `td = $("<td/>")` . And you can use `append()` (http://api.jquery.com/append/) to dynamically add element to it.